# How to get a simple recursive function to work without static vars

Tags: php, function, recursion

Please note the below is just a demo, and I know it can be solved with static variables, however I am trying to work out why it doesn't work without static variables.

The below recursive function should create an array with 10 values, however it is only returning an array with a single value.

```
function test_function($return_array,$j) { 
    $j++;
    $return_array[$j]='dave';
    if($j<10){
        test_function($return_array,$j);    
    }
    return $return_array;
}

$sample_array=test_function(array(),0);
print_r($sample_array);
```

Thanks to any responders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass your initial array per reference:

```
function test_function(&$return_array,$j) {
   $j++;
   $return_array[$j]='dave';
   if($j<10){
       test_function($return_array,$j);
   }
   return $return_array;
}


$sample_array=test_function(($tmpvar = array()),0);
print_r($sample_array);
```

Comment: Wow, that's what I need.. I will have to google that.. thanks Freaud

Comment: edited a little to make the no-need-for-external-vars even more clear :)